# jQuery : Click and clone bug

Tags: jquery, clone

Click on a link, then I'd like to execute an animation after cloning an element.
But I've unexpected results. To test : http://jsfiddle.net/r4BVb/3/

On multiple link click (like a geek), clone is proceed many times.

```
$('#clone').click(function(){
    $('.view_right').clone().prependTo('.overflowed');
    $('.view_right:last').css('display', 'none');
    $('.view_right:first').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 300, function() {
        $('.view_right:last').show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300, function() {
           $('.view_right:first').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

How can I solve this ? Thanks

Comment: maybe you should just prevent the user from clicking the link again before the last animation has finished

Comment: This should get you over the hump until someone gives you a real answer, i consider this a hack. http://jsfiddle.net/r4BVb/4/

Comment: i don't consider that as a hack. It would be one if it would be only about animation, but the main problem here is the clone function and therefore this is not as bad as it looks like on the first view ;-)

Comment: @David: yea, but I'm not confident in it being the _right_ way to solve this.

Comment: I've found another solution : detect that there's only one '.view_right' so i'm sure I can clone >>> http://jsfiddle.net/r4BVb/6/

Comment: @David: that one suffers from some stutter due to the selector having to evaluate the DOM on spam clicks. I feel like there is a clean `.one()` solution here somewhere.

Comment: @Marc : Thanks for this new event .one() but with .one() the handler is unbound after its first invocation

Comment: @David: see my answer below, check out the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
var called = false;

$('#clone').click(function(){
    if (called) {
        return;
    }
    called = true;

    $('.view_right').clone().prependTo('.overflowed');
    $('.view_right:last').css('display', 'none');
    $('.view_right:first').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 300, function() {
        $('.view_right:last').show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300, function() {
           $('.view_right:first').remove();

            called = false;

        });
    });
});
```

[Test it](http://jsfiddle.net/r4BVb/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will add a lot of clones to view_right, so I suggest to check you're not adding too many like this:

```
if($('.view_right').length < 2) {
```

And the result will be http://jsfiddle.net/r4BVb/7/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Using .one()](http://jsfiddle.net/r4BVb/10/)

I'm effectively rebinding the click after animation and only listening to the click event once.